# MySQL Update existing value with Inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I am updating a summary table from detail table using inner join as follows

```
drop TEMPORARY table if exists summ ;
drop TEMPORARY table if exists det  ;

create TEMPORARY table summ (id int , val int ) ;
create TEMPORARY table det (id int , val int ) ;

insert into summ(id,val) value (1,0) ;
insert into summ(id,val) value (2,0) ;

insert into det(id,val) value (1,10) ;
insert into det(id,val) value (1,10) ;
insert into det(id,val) value (1,20) ;

update summ inner join det on summ.id = det.id 
set summ.val = summ.val+ det.val  ;

select * from summ  where id = 1;
```

Its showing Value of val is 10 instead of 40 .. what is wrong  ?
I am using Mysql 5.1 on windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try joining the table against a subquery which calculates the total `val` for every `ID`.

```
UPDATE  summ 
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  id, SUM(VAL) totalVal
            FROM    det
            GROUP   BY id
        ) det ON summ.id = det.id 
SET     summ.val = det.totalVal
```

Comment: yes its working with subquery ...I have already tested that ... But what wrong with this one ??

Comment: the update only run once for every ID even if it has joined multiple records -- reason to have only 10. `summ.val = summ.val+ det.val` -- this doesn't perform running total.

Comment: Hi John. I have doubt can you solve it? What is an equivalent of `GROUP_CONCAT` in [this situation](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a085e/3)? It gives expected result [in MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7b4d/2). How can we achieve that in SQL Server?

Comment: @hims056 try using `MAX()` or `MIN()`. I'll be going home now. be back later. `:)`

Comment: @JW웃 - Is `MAX` and `MIN` are actually valid for situation? Or there is any other function like [STUFF](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1cf2b/2) Reply me when you get time :)

Answer (score 0):

Your going about it the log way. Try replacing lines 14 and 15 with this:
update summ

```
set summ.val = (select sum(det.vat) from det where det.id = summ.id);
```

Or do you really need the temp tables.

Take a look into group by and sum.